# issue when invoking findObjectsInBackGroundWithBlock() with Parse in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Using Parse in my project, i have this line

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject], error:NSError) -> Void in      })
```

But Xcode keeps telling me :

```
cannot invoke this method with an argument list `([PFObject],NSError)`.
```

Any idea why??

Comment: I wish swift would provide more helpful error messages. Why wouldn't it display the actual params vs. the expected ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of at the end of each parameter having an exclamation point at the end of it, change the ! to a ? So it would be

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

That was what I tried and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 closure parameters are both optionals, declared as implicitly unwrapped:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                                              ^                ^
```

Also, I think that the first argument should be `[AnyObject]!` and not `[PFObject]!` - not sure, so I suggest you to verify that.

Comment: Reading your answer I've tried this:   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
               
            })
Still the same comment!

Comment: Found it with ? for both closures!